# Overriding window.fetch prototype it add custom header

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I would like to override window.fetch in order to add some custom headers to all ajax requests, something similar to the way xhr can be overridden.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    var newSend = function(vData) {
    this.setRequestHeader('ClientId', 'ANDROID');
    this.setRequestHeader('CustId', '%s');
    this.realSend(vData);
};
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
```

I want to be able to to do this inside a webview on android. I have tried add custom headers using shouldInterceptUrl (e.g. https://artemzin.com/blog/use-okhttp-to-load-resources-for-webview/ ) but it is something that is not recommended.

Comment: don't overide it, intercept it and edit the headers with a service worker and use the [fetchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent)

Comment: can you please give me an example. I mostly work with native java for android ..I am not very good with javascript :( .

Comment: There you go, there is simplier way to do it also, like how [fetch-cookie](https://github.com/valeriangalliat/fetch-cookie/blob/master/index.js) did it for the server side

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on the page we need to register a service worker

```
<script>
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
</script>
```

sw.js

```
// sw.js
function isWhatYouWant(request){
    // check request if we should add headers
    return true
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {

    if( isWhatYouWant(event.request) ){
        event.request.headers.set('ClientId', 'ANDROID');
        event.request.headers.set('CustId', '%s');
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }

}
```

**PS**: I haven't tested it it's a quite a task to set it up and have a service worker whitelisted and be able to register it, not even sure this is 100% correct but close at least

Also not sure if it works in android webview

Comment: Thank you but his did not work for me. But I was able to override XMLHttpRequest after backend made some changes.